# Filenames with the comparison word "or"

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, cmd

The following works perfectly in a Windows cmd batch file to find file names with the comparison word "or" on my hard drive and move it to a directory called "I Found It":

```
for /r %%a IN (*or*) do (mkdir "I Found It" & move /y "%%a" "I Found It")
```

However, I don't want to include *every* file name with "or" in it such as "ordinary.txt", "order.mp3". I *just* want file names that are using the word " or " like as in a comparison with leading and trailing whitespaces. "jack or jill.txt" is valid, but "order" is not.

How can I do it?

Comment: Just use: `for /r %%a IN ("* or *") do ...`  (w/ leading and trailing whitespaces)...

Comment: @Aacini THAAAAAAAAAAATS the one! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you're happy to keep the source structure too, you could try, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe . ".\I Found It" "* or *" /Mov /S 1>NUL```.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below:

```
@echo off

:rem Create a new directory called "I Found It"
mkdir "I Found It"

:rem Iterate through all files in the current directory and its subdirectories
for /r %%a in (* or *) do (

  rem Check if the file name contains the word " or " with leading and trailing whitespaces
  if "%%~nxa"==" or " (

    rem Move the file to the "I Found It" directory
    move /y "%%a" "I Found It"

  )

)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer however there are no results as I don't think that the spaces in (* or *) are being interpreted correctly by the windows command prompt...

Comment: Like is there an character equivalent for a "spacebar" perhaps?

Comment: **1-** The `for /r %%a in (* or *) do (` indicate: search all files (\*), then just the file named "or", and finally search all files (\*) again...  **2-** The `if "%%~nxa"==" or " (` checks if the filename and extension is precisely `" or "` (space-or-space)...

Comment: Several of your answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.